# How do I perform an accent insensitive compare in SQL Server for 1250 codepage

Tags: sql-server, codepages, accent-insensitive

There are already sever question and solution on accent insensitive search on stackoverflow, but none of them work for codepage 1250 (Central European and Eastern European languages).

[How do I perform an accent insensitive compare (e with è, é, ê and ë) in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461522/how-do-i-perform-an-accent-insensitive-compare-e-with-%C3%A8-%C3%A9-%C3%AA-and-%C3%AB-in-sql-ser)

[LINQ Where Ignore Accentuation and Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418624/linq-where-ignore-accentuation-and-case?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Ignoring accents in SQL Server using LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322441/ignoring-accents-in-sql-server-using-linq-to-sql)

Modify search to make it Accent Insensitive in SQL Server

[Questions about accent insensitivity in SQL Server (Latin1_General_CI_AS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525981/questions-about-accent-insensitivity-in-sql-server-latin1-general-ci-as)

The problem is that accent insensitive collation are bidned to some specific codepages and that I am missing accent insensitive collation for 1250 codepage in [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx).

I need to modify the collation of the column to [make Entity Framework working in accent insensitive way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357351/ignoring-accents-while-searching-the-database-using-entity-framework).

For example if I change a collation to SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AI, c with accute is select as c without accute (U+0107) because wrong codepage.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.fn_helpcollations()
WHERE  COLLATIONPROPERTY(name, 'CodePage') = 1250
       AND description LIKE '%accent-insensitive%';
```

Returns 264 results to choose from.

Picking the first one

```
SELECT N'è' COLLATE Albanian_CI_AI
UNION
SELECT N'é'
UNION
SELECT N'ê'
UNION
SELECT N'ë'
```

returns a single row as desired (showing all compared equal)

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems that the link MSDN documentation is for SQL server 2008 I use SQL Server 2014, but I was not able to find any collation documentation for 2014.

But the solution is to list the collations from server for my code page:

```
SELECT name, COLLATIONPROPERTY(name, 'CodePage') AS CodePage
FROM fn_helpcollations()
where COLLATIONPROPERTY(name, 'CodePage') = 1250
ORDER BY name;
```

And I can see there is a undocumented collation Czech_100_CI_AI **which works for me**. Heureka!