# Accent insensitive search using EF6 and SQL Server 2008 R2 - Czech language

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-6

How to do accent insensitive search query using SQL Server 2008 R2 and EF 6?

I need to do accent insensitive search on let's say `user.name` column using the Entity framework 6. I have tried to change the collation on column from default `Czech_CI_AS` to `Czech_CI_AI`. But it does not work for some Czech letters with wedges like Č, Ř, Š, Ž  because the collation treats them as different letters :

http://collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.0405.1250.Czech_CI_AI.html

I have found similar question here:

[How do I perform an accent insensitive compare in SQL Server for 1250 codepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460408/how-do-i-perform-an-accent-insensitive-compare-in-sql-server-for-1250-codepage)

But the proposed solution using collation `Czech_100_CI_AI` does not work either (for those special letters).

I have also found few sources how to do it in plain T-SQL. Like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[User] 
WHERE name LIKE '%c%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

It works fine. But I do not want to use plain SQL queries. I would like to manage it in an EF way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have end up with this solution:

Create view with two columns - one for the search, second for presentation (latin collation will remove some accents from the result).

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_UserSearch]
AS
SELECT    
           dbo.[User].name AS FirstName,
           dbo.[User].name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI AS FirstNameCI
FROM       dbo.[User]
```

Create DB mapping for the view in EF context.

Use the `FirstNameCI` column for the search in EF.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.FirstName))
   query = query.Where(x => x.c.FirstNameCI.StartsWith(filter.FirstName));
```

Use the `FirstName` column for presentation.

Answer (score 1):

In Entity Framework, when you use `Contains()` method in `where()` extension method in `IQueryable`, it is translated to `where` clause with `like` operator in SQL. So I guess this is what are you looking for. You can refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708715/entity-framework-ef-functions-like-vs-string-contains).

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. from what I understand, the problem is the accent-sensitivity of the search, not how to perform a search using EF...

Comment: Well, OP stated that query with `LIKE` operator works perfectly, so I pointed, how he can achieve that query :)

Comment: Yes, with the `collate`... I don't know if EF lets you specify that.

Comment: @Michal Turczyn: Yes, but it is not because of `LIKE` operator but because of Latin collation. `StartsWith` is also partially translated to `LIKE` statement.